# jQuery Flot time-based axis panning issue

Tags: jquery, flot, panning

I've been tinkering, making a little chart with Flot and some of it's plugins. The purpose is to provide a chart tracking basal body temperature, with the date per day on the x axis, degrees on the y axis. Panning will shift the x axis, so you can see previous dates etc, clicking will result in a new point, snapped to grid.

The grid on a time based axis when panning does not move. It does when I change the axis type to normal. I really want to have the entire grid move, because now the line series sort of 'floats around' on the grid. Does anyone know how to make that work? Am I missing something in the options?

This is harder to explain than it is to see, so fsfiddle provided: http://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/caM3q/1/

Triggering the change in behaviour is the option `mode: 'time'` on the x axis option (line 24 of the fiddle).

The bit of code to pay attention to:

```
        xaxis: {
            show: true,
            min: firstDay,
            max: lastDay,
            ticks: 31,
            mode: 'time',
            timezone: 'browser',
            timeformat: '%d. %m'
        },
```

change this to

```
        xaxis: {
            show: true,
            min: firstDay,
            max: lastDay,
            ticks: 31,
        },
```

and see what happens moving the graph after adding a few points.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a combination of two things:

1. There was a bug in 0.8.0 that we just fixed, so if you try with [jquery.flot.time.js](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.time.js) from master, you'll immediately notice an improvement.
2. Even with the fix, the ticks will still jump around a bit.  That's because you have a large enough range that the ticks only appear every ~3 days.  Internally, however, the tick generator still sees one day as the minimum interval.  It therefore recalculates as soon as you pan by a day, even if that was only a third of the tick interval's size.

You can usually work around that problem by assigning a suitably high minTickSize; `[5, 'day']`, for example, to convince the tick generator that it doesn't need to recalculate.  This works best when you know the plot's dimensions ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks for that! That does seem to have sorted the scrolling grid issue. It is my intention to show a month in full, so roughly 30 gridlines, one for each day. Would that be `minTickSize: [1,'day']`? Up until know i've just put number of ticks to 30.

Comment: With minTickSize Flot will typically pick a larger interval.  If you instead use `tickSize: [1, "day"]` it'll be closer to what you want.  Make sure you understand how much space 30 ticks take up, though.  At 400px wide, 8-10 ticks is the maximum that can fit comfortably; to fit 30 you'll need a width of at least 1200.

Comment: Yeah, I had picked 1200 already, which is pretty good. I adjusted the fiddle to make it fit the little frame better. I might drop it to two weeks if that turns out to be to large. Thanks for your help!